# Trying to run Cypress through CLI, but getting an error

Tags: cypress

Today is my first day of trying out Cypress and I am following one of their video tutorials they have on their [website](https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/tutorials.html#Test-a-React-Todo-App). I ran the following command in my terminal and I am getting an error. It won't let me open up Cypress and it displays the following message:

```
Cypress cannot run because this binary file does not have executable permissions here:

/Users/name/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.5.0/Cypress.app/Contents/MacOS/Cypress

Reasons this may happen:

- node was installed as 'root' or with 'sudo'
- the cypress npm package as 'root' or with 'sudo'

Please check that you have the appropriate user permissions.
```

I added the script to my package.json folder like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "serve": "json-server db.json",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "cypress: "cypress open" 
},
```

Does anyone know how to potentially fix the issue? The project I am using to follow the tutorial is a project I cloned from Cypress' GitHub page and it had already Cypress installed its starter [file](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-tutorial-build-todo-starter). I did not once install Cypress.

Comment: I did some more research and I was able to find the answer [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6516)